# What is a Spiel/Spieg Word™?

Tags: pattern, movies, word-property

Here's my first puzzle attributed to the fortnightly topic, [movies](/questions/tagged/movies). I figured I'd try my hand at this series of pattern recognition puzzles.

Below is a chart listing words that fall into one or neither of two categories, Spiel Words™ and Spieg Words™ (though it should be noted that all Spieg Words™ are also Spiel Words™, they are just a more specific categorization). Mathematically speaking, the set of all Spieg Words is a subset of the set of all Spiel Words

#### Spieg Words™:

> Cow
>   Law
>   Urn
>   Dear
>   Hear
>   Lamb
>   Lock
>   Made
>   Pear
>   Week
>   West
>   Apart
>   Liver
>   Ridge
>   Round
>   People

#### Spiel Words™:

> Amp
>   Far
>   Red
>   Two
>   Atom
>   East
>   Find
>   Lace
>   Lose
>   Clock
>   Close
>   Range
>   South
>   Versa
>   Ground
>   Tenant
>   Picture

#### Neither

> Oil
>   Buck
>   Dean
>   Dirt
>   Sear
>   Vice
>   Block
>   Crazy
>   Filth
>   Irate
>   North
>   Shark
>   Thief
>   Energy
>   Figure
>   Future
>   Zombie
>   Abridge
>   Electricity

Can you determine the rule I use to decide if I call it a Spiel Word™, a Spieg Word™, or neither? Feel free to ask below for certain words, but I ask that to avoid spamming up the question, if you have multiple, please ask them all at once.

Comment: Is this like a continuation of that other guy's posts?

Comment: what's with the tm jazz ?

Comment: So the formal category "Spiel Words™", contains Spieg Words™, that are also Spiel Words™. And "Spieg Words™" contains words that are **only** Spieg Words™, but not Spiel Words™.

Comment: By definition, all Spieg Words are Spiel Words. Not all Spiel Words are Spieg Words however. The set of Spieg words is a subset of the set of Spiel Words

Comment: Please can you test the following words: Close, Shark, Future?

Comment: Close is Spiel, Shark and Future are neither.

Comment: Electricity, picture, lamb, zombie?

Comment: Zombie and Electricity are neither, Picture is Spiel, and Lamb is Spieg

Comment: Could we get a hint for this?

Comment: @alexmc well, I could tell you that originally, I had Spieg words called Be words and Spiel words were termed No words. Recalling the context of movies, does that help?

Comment: I can't help but think this have something to do with Steven Spielberg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"I had Spieg words called Be words and Spiel words were termed No words." This did it for me.

> Spieg words are substrings in *Best Picture Academy Award winners*, Spiel words are substrings in *nominees*

A few examples:

> **Spieg**
>
> Midnight ***Cow***boy
>
> ***Law***rence of Arabia
>
> The Lord of the Rings Ret***urn*** of the King
>
> **Spiel**
>
> The Ch***amp***
>
> A ***Far***ewell to Arms
>
> Mild***red*** Pierce

etc.

> All winners (Spieg words) were nominees, but not all nominees (Spiel words) won.

Comment: Well done! Have a bounty for figuring it out after all this time (in 23 hours anyways when I can award it)

Comment: Thank you! This one had me stumped, because I just wasn't making the connection to "movies"